# How do I get the value of 'columnwidth'?

Tags: floats, two-column, acm

I am using the [ACM SIG Template](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) for a conference paper (a two-column document). And I'd like to insert several figures plotted by matplotlib.

I was wondering what is the width I should set for `fig.set_size_inches` in matplotlib.

```
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(w, h, forward=False)
```

Is it equevilent to `columnwidth` in ACM SIG? However, I didn't find the definition  of `columnwidth` in `sig-alternate-05-2015.cls`.

```
$ grep 'columnwidth' sig-alternate-05-2015.cls 
  \hrule width .5\columnwidth   % (was .4) updated Gerry March 20 2007
        \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
```

Comment: use `\showthe\columnwidth` and TeX  will stop and show the value in pt, divide by 72.27 and that is the width in inches

Comment: thx. the result is `240.0/72.27 = 3.32`.